# I need help to make my bones only move certain mesh!

Tags: mesh, bones, edit-mode

I tried applying an armature for a jacket that I would like to add to an avatar I'm creating but the bones are moving too much mesh.
([image](https://gyazo.com/6764e6c6edcb1a5a22caf766c8491cff))

[image: screenshot of the jacket]

I just wonder if anyone knows how to fix this easily or hardly however just wanna fix it. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It's hard to help, was your mesh in T pose when you've parented? have you tried to fix it in Weight Paint mode?

Comment: no i moved the arms of the armature down to fit the jack and then i merged it. Did try to fix it in weight painting but did not help

Comment: if you move down the arms, do it in Edit mode, not Pose mode. I'm not sure it's a good idea though because a T pose will calculate the vertex groups better

Comment: So like move the jacket into a tpose and then merge it with the armature?

Comment: both the object and the armature need to be in T pose before parenting, it will help to have a better calculation of the vertex groups

Comment: so i tried with a different clothing that was actually t posed but its still moving mesh the wrong way. (look at pictures)

Comment: https://gyazo.com/cec63263bda5300077f3070801c280b6 https://gyazo.com/3c0e24774d5e0900d799237bcc7d90c8

Comment: what do you mean by it moves it the wrong way? maybe share your file?